# How can I play audio or video with speech at a selected constant speed of e.g. 200 words per minute?

Tags: swift, nlp, avfoundation, speech

I want to import an audio or video file and

1. shorten long pauses between words or sentences into short pauses.
2. then play AV at a previously selected constant speed of e.g. 200 words per minute.

**Example**: Instead of playing a podcast at 1.5x or 2.0x speed, **I want a smooth listening experience without long pauses** (1.) and **at a constant speed (2.) of 200 words per minute.**

Is this natively possible in Swift? Or does one have to look into NLP?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It's natively possible in Swift if you are an expert in audio signal processing and are prepared to invest a huge amount of time. However, there are likely signal processing frameworks that would make it much easier.

Comment: I think you may be approaching this from the wrong start point. What you should first do is prototype your algorithm, probably in a non-real-time setting using a language / platform amicable for prototyping before advancing to a real-time implementation. After that your questions will be _how  do I implement my algorithm in Swift_ which will need to be broken down into smaller parts and then attempted before you will likely get a helpful answer from SO